# What is the probability that in a sample of $5$ people that all of them are blonde? at least two of them are blonde?

Tags: probability

I am dealing with this probability problem and I am stuck. I would really appreciate if you could please help me. Thanks in advance.

> In a population of $80$ people, $30\%$ are blonde and $70\%$ are black-haired. If we take a sample of $5$ guys,
>
> 1. what is the probability that all of them are blonde?
> 2. what is the probability that at least two of them are blonde?

I have thought for the first one that it should be , by Laplace's rule, $\frac{24\choose 5}{80\choose 5}$. But, I also would say that it is true that it is a binomial distribution and thus it should be $(0.3)^5$. Nevertheless, these answers do not coincide.

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Okey, thank you for your suggestion. I just added this information.

Comment: A population of $12$ and $30$ percent are blond... So there are 3.6 blond persons. Weird, I would say that the number of persons is always a nonnegative integer.

Comment: The question is (as drhab points out) quite unclear and cannot really be answered before you explain the confusion.

Comment: It was a tipo. Should say 15. Changed. Thanks!

Comment: Even with your edit to $15$ people, $30\%$ of $15$ is $4.5$ so you didn't really explain anything.

Comment: I put now good numbers. Sorry!

Comment: Agree with all of you. The numbers were not correct. Now they are. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If it is a selection of $5$ distinct persons out of $80$ then hypergeometric distribution must be applied (as you did). Not binomial. That must be applied if the persons are *replaced* after selection so that a person can be selected more than once. So your answer of 1) is okay. Do you still want an answer on 2)?

Comment: Yes, please! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a selection of $5$ distinct persons out of $80$ then hypergeometric distribution must be applied (as you did). Not binomial. That must be applied if the persons are *replaced* after selection so that a person can be selected more than once. So your answer of 1) is okay.

Also for 2) we use hypergeometric distribution and if $W$ denotes the number of blondes we find probability:$$P(W\geq2)=\sum_{w=2}^5P(W=w)=\sum_{w=2}^5\frac{\binom{24}w\binom{56}{5-w}}{\binom{80}5}$$

A summation of $4$ terms. We can make it a bit less complicated like this:$$P(W\geq2)=1-P(W\leq1)=1-P(W=0)-P(W=1)=1-\frac{\binom{24}0\binom{56}{5}}{\binom{80}5}-\frac{\binom{24}1\binom{56}{4}}{\binom{80}5}$$